# Windows 10: Ethernet slow, unstable or not working at all after unplugging Ethernet cable

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet

Since a few months I have from time to time a strange problem.

The Problem:

Usually my laptop is using Ethernet for internet. However, sometimes I will unplug this cable to take my laptop to another room or to work. When I then reconnect the Ethernet cable there is always a chance that after that either my Ethernet connection is very slow or not working at all. Sometimes it will then also switch between being just slow and not working at all. This does not happen every time I dis- and reconnect the Ethernet cable but often enough to be really annoying.

Windows troubleshoot is in these cases never helpful and producees a wide range of error messages including the following:

- ethernet doesn't have a valid ip configuration
- Investigate router or broadband issues. (Resetting the router never solves the issue)
- The default gateway is not available
- DNS Server Not Responding
- DHCP is not enabled for "ethernet"

I should mention that running the troubleshooter multiple times in a row will often produce different error messages. Another common problem is that my Ethernet connection simply only shows up as an "unidentified network".

Solutions I tried:

So the really strange thing for me is that there is not one solution to this problem I describe. Every time it happens I cycle through a number of steps to solve the issue and sometimes one will work. Things I usually try include:

- Renew IP address
- Reset TCP/IP Stack
- Disable/Enable Network Adapter
- Change DNS settings
- Restart Router and Laptop
- Clear the DNS cache

Usually after some trying one of these solutions is working. However, it is not always the same solution that is working and if I am unlucky I have to go through the list multiple times until the Ethernet connection works again.

This is of course somewhat inconvenient and it also makes no sense to me why some solutions are only sometimes working. So I wanted to ask if any of you has an idea what is wrong with my Laptop/Ethernet and how I could possible fix it.

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: I should add that Wifi works always fine on my laptop and wifi and ethernet work without any problems on all other devices connected to the router

Comment: Try another cable, and verify that the port is in good shape.

Comment: I'm with harry - power down completely, get a new cable. Spray the plug liberally with contact cleaner [never spray in the socket of a laptop even powered off], then holding the little lock down, push in & out of your laptop socket a couple of dozen times. Unplug & allow to dry for 5 minutes. Do the same for the other end of the cable. Cables do go bad, but socket contacts do get grubby too, which can cause all kinds of intermittent issues like you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I will try another cable and a contact cleaner and report back.